# Embedding DocuSign, is that an option for me?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign to add **eSignature** to my requests and everything's working well. Right now I send my signature requests through email but sometimes I want to allow people to sign right away and not have to wait for an email, is there any way to do this? I saw a brief mention about something called Embedding DocuSign, is that an option for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I know DocuSign well and this is absolutely possible.  You are right in that you want to use Embedding, with Embedding you can generate URL tokens to access envelopes as a sender or recipient, and you can also use it to access the DocuSign Console.

The following two resources have all the info you need including working examples of Embedded functionality in 6 different languages.  I'd start by reading about them on the DocuSign Developer Center in the [Explore -> Features section](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features)

Then they have their API Walkthroughs which are EXTREMELY valuable for Embedding and other use cases.  [Check out the bottom three 3 squares for Embedding](http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs)